# Disable confirmation on delete request in PHPhotoLibrary delete Assets?

Tags: ios, ipad, photokit, phphotolibrary

My question is how can I disable confirmation on delete request on  [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assets], if my application created that assets , so my app should  able to delete assets without confirmation?

```
   [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{ [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assets];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? @"Success." : error.description));
 }];
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

At the moment where the file is saved, it belongs to the system.
So if you want to remove this file later, the user will always be informed by a message.

It's part of the PHPhotoLibrary.. I know it's suck.